# Makefile compiles all tsc regardless of changes

Tags: typescript, makefile, gnu-make

## Question

I wrote a makefile to compile all of my typescript files to javascript, but also run them through a linter (tslint). I wrote the following makefile:

```
#binaries
SASS=./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass
TSC=tsc
TSLINT=tslint

#source dirs
SASS_DIRS=./apps ./lib
TS_DIRS=./apps ./lib ./library

#source files
SASS_SRC ::=  $(shell find $(SASS_DIRS) -name '*.scss')
TS_SRC ::= $(shell find $(TS_DIRS) -name '*.ts')
APPS_SASS_SRC ::= $(shell find ./apps -name 'app.scss')
MAIN_SASS_SRC=./library/incode/incode.scss
MAIN_SASS_DEST=./library/incode/incode.css

#compilation options/binary flags
SASS_FLAGS = --output-style compressed -q
TSC_FLAGS = --sourceMap -t ES5 --noEmitOnError

.PHONY: clean

all: tsc sass

sass scss: $(patsubst %.scss, %.css, $(SASS_SRC))

%.css: %.scss
    $(SASS) $(SASS_FLAGS) $< > $@

tsc: $(patsubst %.ts, %.js, $(TS_SRC))
    $(TSC) $(TSC_FLAGS) $(TS_SRC)

%.js: %.ts
    $(TSLINT) $<

incodesass: $(MAIN_SASS_SRC)
     touch $(APPS_SASS_SRC); $(SASS) $(SASS_FLAGS) $< > $(MAIN_SASS_DEST); make sass

clean:
    $(shell for i in $(shell find -name '*.rej'); do rm $i; done; for i in $(shell find -name '*.orig'); do rm $i; done;)
```

The problem is that any time I run `make` (or equivalently `make all`), the scss and tslint rules only run on changed files as appropriate, but even if I've changed no typescript files, the tsc recipe runs it's command (`$(TSC) $(TSC_FLAGS) $(TS_SRC)`). What did I do wrong?

## Note

From what I understand of typescript, even if only one file was changed, all the files need to be recompiled so it can understand references that they make between them, which is fair I suppose. With that in mind, this makefile needs to run `tslint` on each **individual** typescript source file, but also must run `tsc` on **all** of the source typescript files if even just one of them is changed. (currently it does that, the problem is just that `tsc` runs even if nothing's changed)

## Bonus

You might wonder why I left the sass/scss stuff in at all, it's because every `%.scss` file in `./apps/` `@import`s my main scss file (`$(MAIN_SASS_SRC)`) and I'd like it to run something that first checks if that's been changed, and if so `touch`es all the app scuzzy files so they re-import it but regardless runs the sass/scss recipe AFTER that has completed. I can't think of a way to do this without a race condition (since I'm using `-j`) that doesn't involve running make twice or without submakes. In general, I'm pretty new to this, so I'd happily accept criticisms on any part of this makefile in the comments, as well as a solution to that specific problem.

Comment: I am saddened that anyone is using Make for anything remotely modern :(

Comment: What? Not only is that not relevant, but make is the best tool for this job. I've clocked this particular makefile at approximately 4 times faster than gulp, and it's running in cygwin. Related: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7622296

Comment: A passing comment of surprise!  7 years of using Make for C/C++ convinced me that its use for any project of non-trivial complexity quickly devolves into layers of arcane syntax, nested sed/awk/Perl hacks (or alternatively, metaprogramming e.g. Automake), or copy-and-paste boilerplate.  YMMV of course.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree with you that Make, while theoretically a good tool, in practice on large projects, with many engineers, does not work well.  Is there another tool that you think is better?

Comment: I strongly disagree, I work with a company that is deploying management software for local governments, and my makefile is a third the lines and runs in a fourth the time. PS if he says gulp is better I will no longer be able to find my shit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told make you're creating the file `tsc`, but the recipe doesn't create it.

Use the output files themselves as dependencies

```
SASS_CSS := $(SASS_SRC:=.scss=.css)
TS_JS    := $(TS_SRC:.ts=.js)

.PHONY: all js.stub

all: $(SASS_CSS) $(TS_JS)

%.css: %.scss
    $(SASS) $(SASS_FLAGS) $< > $@

$(TS_JS): %.js: %.ts js.stub
    $(TSLINT) $<

js.stub: $(TS_SRC)
    $(TSC) $(TSC_FLAGS) $^
    @touch $@
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, I thought recipe names were separate from files, and `all` would just inherit dependencies. By the way, "`SASS_CSS := $(SASS_SRC:=.csss=.css)`"... never seen that, is it shorthand for `patsubst` or something else altogether?

Comment: @bfieck [Exactly](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs). As for targets that aren't actually files, that's what `PHONY` targets are for, but making `tsc` phony wouldn't help here because phony targets are *always* run.

Comment: @bfieck I edited the answer, as for the linter it'll require a little more thought.

Comment: couldn't I just add a rule for `%.js: %.ts` that lints it? Either way, I'll check this new answer out and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @bfieck Make will only execute one set of recipes for any given target (unless you use double colon rules), it'd be a lot easier if you packed your js into a single file.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, things have been busy lately. I'm gonna accept this answer because I believe it to be correct, but for what it's worth I was able to accomplish this without a double-colon rule. Furthermore, rather than a `.PHONY` `js.stub` target, I just made TS_SRC depend on the first entry in TS_JS. Then you can build that (which depends on TS_SRC) using `$(TSLINT) $?; $(TSC) $(TSC_FLAGS) $(TS_SRC)` source: Professor Keith Hellman at Colorado School of Mines

Answer (score 0):

I know I've already accepted an answer, but I thought it was worth mentioning that there's a different way to accomplish this.

```
#binaries
TSC=tsc
TSLINT=tslint

#source dir
TS_DIRS=./apps ./lib ./library

#source files
TS_SRC ::= $(shell find $(TS_DIRS) -name '*.ts')

#compilation options/binary flags
TSC_FLAGS = --sourceMap -t ES5 --noEmitOnError

#outfiles
JS_OUT ::= $(patsubst %.ts, %.js, $(TS_SRC))

.PHONY: all

all: $(word 1, $(JS_OUT))

$(word 1, $(JS_OUT)): $(TS_SRC)
    $(TSLINT) $?
    $(TSC) $(TSC_FLAGS) $(TS_SRC)
```

A professor at my college helped me with this. Since whenever a single `.ts` source file changes, all of them need to be rebuilt, I can make my target any one of the javascript output files. That way, I'm telling make the truth, that this rule will produce its target. `$?` gets all of the dependencies for the recipe that have changed, so only the files that have changed go through the linter. In contrast, the second line directly compiles all of the source files.

An added bonus of this is that while `make -j` will thread each recipe for each target, the build has to be performed sequentially, so the relatively lengthy `tsc` step won't occur if one of the files fails to lint, effectively improving the makefile's average execution time (because I'm a moron that messes up all the time)

## Bonus

I know it's probably frowned upon to ask more than one question in a post, but I already did it, and since I have an answer I feel obliged to share it. Rebuilding all of the `.css` files was actually pretty easy:

```
#binaries
SASS=./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

#source dir
SASS_DIRS=./apps
#I used to rebuild './lib' every time, not necessary as it turns out.

#source files
SASS_SRC ::=  $(shell find $(SASS_DIRS) -name '*.scss')
MAIN_SASS_SRC=./library/incode/incode.scss
MAIN_SASS_DEST=./library/incode/incode.css

#compilation options/binary flags
SASS_FLAGS = --output-style compressed -q

.PHONY: all

all: sass

sass: $(patsubst %.scss, %.css, $(SASS_SRC))

%.css: %.scss $(MAIN_SASS_DEST)
    $(SASS) $(SASS_FLAGS) $< > $@

$(MAIN_SASS_DEST): $(MAIN_SASS_SRC)
    $(SASS) $(SASS_FLAGS) $< > $(MAIN_SASS_DEST)
```

because *every* `apps/*.scss` file was `@import`ing my main scuzzy file, all I had to do was make every single one dependent on the main one. Frankly, I'm disappointed with myself for not figuring this out without help.

Comment: In some TypeScript projects, you will have `.d.ts` files that don't generate a corresponding `.js` file. In that case, you might want to declare your TypeScript dependencies as `$(shell find src -name "*.ts" -not -name "*.d.ts")`